# SFML Mouse Event in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sfml

I've follow [this](http://becomingindiedev.blogspot.com/2013/10/qt-5-and-sfml-20-integration.html?showComment=1395383850229) tutorial to create RenderWindow in QFrame.

Everything fine, except this

`sf::Vector2i pixelPos = sf::Mouse::getPosition();
sf::Vector2f worldPos = RenderWindow::mapPixelToCoords(pixelPos);`

In `sf::Mouse::getPosition();`
It refer the mouse position of my screen, not refer to my QFrame.

What variable should I fill in `()` of `sf::Mouse::getPosition`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class QSFMLCanvas : public QWidget, public sf::RenderWindow` hence you can call `sf::Mouse::getPosition(*this)` from within your class' methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
sf::Mouse::GetPosition(sf::RenderWindow &Game);
```

So it is relative to your window, not your full screen.

Comment: `sf::Mouse::getPosition(sf::RenderWindow);` give error, So I use this `sf::Mouse::getPosition(sf::RenderWindow());` but I refer to (0,0) every time I click.

Comment: @delio I meant you have to pass in a reference to your `RenderWindow`, I was just showing the type.

Comment: But problem is I don't know what variable is a reference of my RenderWindow. Please you find it in [this](http://becomingindiedev.blogspot.com/2013/10/qt-5-and-sfml-20-integration.html?showComment=1395383850229) tutorial?